# How to import XmlSyntaxException in This File? *Nuget, Unreal Engine Build, C#

Tags: c#, nuget, unreal, system.security

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itbwK.png)

Hi, I downloaded open source to build the packaging version of Unreal Engine.

This error occurs when trying to build.

`Error CS1069 Namespace 'System.Security' does not have the format 'XmlSyntaxException'. This format was passed to the assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2dd51'. Please add a reference for the assembly.`

If anyone knows why, please let me know. Thank you.

I searched to download XmlSyntaxException on Nuget, but nothing came up. Something seems to be missing from an existing file, but I can't find a way to recover it.

Comment: You need to add a reference to https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Permissions/